# How to trigger a notification badge in swiftui

Tags: swiftui, notifications, updates, badge

I want to create a notification center similar to that on instagram & facebook. The only difference is that the update will be coming from Contentful. So its a simple announcements view. So I want everytime I add a new announcement from Contentful a notification badge displays on the bell icon (image attached) that I have in my view with the number changing based on the amount of new announcements. When the user taps the icon, it will present the announcements view. Once the user taps on the bell icon and views the announcements, the badges will be removed (signalling that they have viewed all available announcements)

How can I create this function?

[Image screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNQ9O.jpg)

Comment: What have you tried? SO isn't a code writing service, so it's helpful to see what you have and then explain where you got stuck and need help. Include your relevant code.

Comment: I haven't actually written any code yet because I honestly dont know where to start. I tried thinking of how it could work but the main issue I'm having is that I dont know how to link the data i'm recieving from Contentful with a func to display the badge. Just an idea of where to start would help